# How to keep text in center on showing an image completely at background

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a `<kbd>` tag for myself. I was trying with [this image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61772690/kbd.png) like below,

CSS:

```
kbd {
    font-family: Courier;
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-bottom:8px;
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-left:10px;
    background: url('kbd.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>Open Terminal  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> </p>
```

But images are not showing completely unless the text is large enough to cover the image. see the screen shot below.

[image: screenshot]

Also I could not able to bring the text at center, I tried `align` but could not succeeded.
Any help including any better way to have `<kbd>` tag will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very worth noting that this could be done pretty much entirely without the need of an image. It would be more flexible without it; a long `<kbd>` text would break if it were an image, but wouldn't if it was done entirely in CSS.

So I propose:

http://jsfiddle.net/TLV4a/1/

```
kbd {

    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 45px;
    text-align: center;

    font-family: Courier;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-width: 1px 1px 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 1px #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 1px #fff;
    line-height: 1.75;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have even padding, instead of different left vs. right padding, as well as utilise a `min-width` along with `text-align: center;`, you can get it to display nicely.

http://jsfiddle.net/TLV4a/

```
kbd {

    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 50px;
    text-align: center;

    font-family: Courier;
    padding: 6px 5px 8px;
    background: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61772690/kbd.png') no-repeat 50% 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgM4U/)

```
kbd {
    font-family: Courier;
    padding-top:6px;
    padding-bottom:6px;
    background: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61772690/kbd.png');
    display: inline-block;
    width: 54px;
    text-align: center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use this code to get your desire resutl:
kbd {
    background: url("kbd.png") no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Courier;
    min-height: 31px;
    min-width: 54px;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    padding: 6px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}
/*use font size to adjust with the key image and use padding  0px for the left and right after that use text-align to obtain your best result .I have attached an image look it*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding background-size may be your best solution.

```
    background-size:100% 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `text-align:center` for align your text and  on the background image you can use a `z-index` Property.

have a look here for z-index examples:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp